# OpenCV VideoWriter produces "can't find starting number" error

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I am trying to write 16-bit grayscale video using the FFV1 codec and opencv.ImageWriter on Windows 10

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, pdb

print(cv2.getBuildInformation())

def to8(img):
    return (img/256).astype('uint8')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0+cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('Y','1','6',' '))
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, False)

out = cv2.VideoWriter('out.avi', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('F','F','V','1'), cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS), (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))))

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.normalize(frame,None,0,65535,cv2.NORM_MINMAX)

    cv2.imshow('Video',to8(frame))
    out.write(frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here is my error:

```
[ERROR:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (415) cv::VideoWriter::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): out.avi in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

I am running this script from a command window with admin privileges. I've tried both making sure the output file does and does not exist before running.

My OpenCV build information is here: https://pastebin.com/whtF6ixG

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Based on Rotem's suggestion, instead of using VideoWriter I piped directly to FFMPEG using ffmpeg-python:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2, pdb
import ffmpeg

def to8(img):
    return (img/256).astype('uint8')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0+cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC, cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('Y','1','6',' '))
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_CONVERT_RGB, False)

ff_proc = (
    ffmpeg
    .input('pipe:',format='rawvideo',pix_fmt='gray16le',s='%sx%s'%(int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))),r='60')
    .output('out3.avi',vcodec='ffv1',an=None)
    .run_async(pipe_stdin=True)
)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    cv2.imshow('Video',to8(frame))
    ff_proc.stdin.write(frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

out.terminate()
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It doesn't look like `VideoWriter` supports 16 bit in Python (It looks like it ignores the array type, and take it as `uint8`). You forgot to set `isColor=False`, but this is not the issue.

Comment: There is no way telling if the problem is related to `VideoCapture` or to `VideoWriter`. I suggest you split them (for testing). I suggest you to generate synthetic video for testing `VideoWriter`. You can use the example from my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855355/taking-images-from-webcam/60857393#60857393) that generates video with increment counter. You can test the `VideoReader` by showing the grabbed frames without writing. Is it working?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm pretty certain that the FFMPEG backend supports 16-bit writing to FFV1, and I think that VideoWriter supports it but I'm not totally clear: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10623

Comment: FFMPEG backend does support 16-bit writing, and it suppose to work in OpenCV with C++. I think it's a Python interface issue, but I am not sure. You can PIPE the output to `FFmpeg` without OpenCV.

Comment: Can you store the output as `uint8` with `MJPG` codec?

Comment: I am able to use a synthetic source to write in that manner, with a FFV1 VideoWriter and creating an array of random numbers (0,65535) of type np.uint16. I can open the video in PotPlayer and it looks about right... (I have commented out everything releated to VideoCapture.)

I am also able to successfully use VideoCapture (without VideoWriter) directly on the video source and printing each frame to a window.

However I am not able to use VideoCapture to read the FILE that I wrote (in FFV1/16bit). It only reads 'None'

Comment: I took your suggestion to pipe to FFmpeg (I used ffmpeg-python) with great success! I'm able to write from VideoCapture in my original intention. Thank you!